# why Java Unsafe CAS (getAndAddInt) is faster than the code by manually written

Tags: java, unsafe, microbenchmark, jmh, compare-and-swap

I wrote the cas code (while loop for compare_and_set) by manual instead of direct invocation of `Unsafe.getAndAddInt` method. But when I use `jmh` to test performance, it shows the big performance lost although i wrote the same code as just copy of the source code of `Unsafe` method. 
Who can help me what makes this big difference? Thanks in advance.

The `jmh` result is:

```
Benchmark              Mode  Cnt  Score   Error  Units
CASTest.casTest        avgt       0.047          us/op
CASTest.manualCasTest  avgt       0.137          us/op
```

the source code is:

```
package org.sample;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Benchmark;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.BenchmarkMode;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Fork;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Measurement;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Mode;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.OutputTimeUnit;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Scope;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.State;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Threads;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Warmup;
import org.openjdk.jmh.infra.Blackhole;
import org.openjdk.jmh.runner.Runner;
import org.openjdk.jmh.runner.RunnerException;
import org.openjdk.jmh.runner.options.Options;
import org.openjdk.jmh.runner.options.OptionsBuilder;
import sun.misc.Unsafe;

/**
 * @author Isaac Gao
 * @Date 2020/2/20
 */
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS)
@State(Scope.Benchmark)
@Threads(2)
@Measurement(iterations = 1, time = 1, timeUnit = TimeUnit.SECONDS)
@Warmup(iterations = 2, time = 1)
@Fork(1)
public class CASTest {

  private static Unsafe getUnsafe() {
    try {
      final Field unsafeField = Unsafe.class.getDeclaredField("theUnsafe");

      unsafeField.setAccessible(true);
      return (Unsafe) unsafeField.get(null);
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
  }
  private static final Unsafe unsafe = getUnsafe();

  private static final long valueOffset;
  static {
    try {
      valueOffset = unsafe.objectFieldOffset
          (CASTest.class.getDeclaredField("value"));
    } catch (Exception ex) { throw new Error(ex); }
  }

  private volatile  int value;

  @Benchmark
  public void manualCasTest(Blackhole bh) {
    int andAddIntManually = getAndAddIntManually(this, valueOffset, 1);
    bh.consume(andAddIntManually);
  }

  @Benchmark
  public void casTest(Blackhole  bh) {
    int andAddInt = unsafe.getAndAddInt(this, valueOffset, 1);
    bh.consume(andAddInt);
  }

  public final int getAndAddIntManually(Object o, long offset, int delta) {
    int v;
    do {
      v = unsafe.getIntVolatile(o, offset);
    } while (!unsafe.compareAndSwapInt(o, offset, v, v + delta));
    return v;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws RunnerException {
    Options opt = new OptionsBuilder()
        .include(CASTest.class.getSimpleName())
        .build();
    new Runner(opt).run();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The executed code doesn’t necessarily match what you’ve seen in the source code. A similar nonmatching performance of copy&pasted code has been discussed in [Does Java JIT cheat when running JDK code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45912510/2711488)

Well known methods may get replaced by special implementations, regardless of whether there original declaration was `native` or had a pure Java implementation. See also [What does 'intrinsify' mean in the JVM source code?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35357160/2711488)

When we look in the JVM source file [`vmSymbols.hpp`, line 1031](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/812ed44725b8/src/share/vm/classfile/vmSymbols.hpp#l1031), we will see that `sun.misc.Unsafe.getAndAddInt` is known to the JVM.

You can use
`-XX:CompileCommand=print,CASTest.casTest` `-XX:CompileCommand=print,CASTest.manualCasTest`
to check the resulting native code (which is generally a good idea for evaluating benchmark results).

On X64, you’ll see that `manualCasTest` will be compiled like you’ve written, a loop centered around a
`lock cmpxchg dword ptr [rsi],ebx` instruction, whereas the `casTest` bears a single loop free
`lock xadd dword ptr [rdx+0ch],r8d` instruction (details may vary).

Comment: See also [How to see JIT-compiled code in JVM?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15146962/2711488)